# How to pass parameter in retrofit2 to Spring rest server?

Tags: spring, retrofit2

My Spring Server mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/allData/{branchID}/{docID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

---

Problem is I can't pass parameter by using Retrofit2 from android

I am trying to :

```
@GET("/allData/{branchID}/{docID}")
Call<List<User>> getUserData(
@Query("branchID") int branchID, @Query("docID") Long docID
);
```

But it's not working. anyone help me please.

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@Path`. `@Query` is for [query string parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

```
@GET("/allPatient/{branchID}/{docID}")
Call<List<Patient>> getUserData(@Path("branchID") int branchID,
                                @Path("docID") Long docID);
```

[See the docs](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. @Path is not working for this map

Comment: What map are you talking about?

Comment: Spring Server mapping:
@RequestMapping(value = "/allPatient/{branchID}/{docID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)